# Coverflow with jQuery and css3

Tags: jquery, css, coverflow

I know this questions has been asked previously, but the questions I saw were about the Apple coverflow and this one isnt.

I am trying to replicate this behaviour:
http://cl.ly/image/1s0L1O3M2401 (screen shot)

Does anyone know if there is a plugin or something?
I can use CSS perpective and rotate to achieve the "skewed" look but it's not working... haha
difficult to explain.

Anyway if anyone knows a plugin that would do that for me, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out Addy Osmani's Jquery UI Coverflow 2.0

http://addyosmani.com/blog/jqueryuicoverflow/

Comment: I've already seen this but it doesnt work the same way. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

Here are two choices for a CSS3 (webkit) light weight solutions:

http://jbkflex.wordpress.com/2012/02/13/coverflow-animation-using-css3-3d-transformations-part1

http://scottgale.com/blog/coverflow-css-3d-transforms/2011/05/24/

Here are two other jQuery methods:

http://www.webappers.com/2012/05/30/apple-coverflow-design-with-coverscroll-jquery-plugin/

http://www.artviper.net/wp/convenient-page-design/apple-coverflow-design-with-coverscroll-jquery-plugin/